# Web scraping - h1 - font access issues

Tags: html, css, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am new to webscraping and have some issues access the HTML and CSS code.

I want to scrape the below website for the title:
https://www.leaseplan.com/nl-nl/privatelease/onze-autos/4662/

Upon clicking on inspect, I found

```
<h1 class="u-margin-bottom-none u-margin-bottom@tablet" data-e2e-id="carName"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;"><font style="vertical-align: inherit;">Fiat 500 - Lounge Hybrid </font></font></h1>
```

I want to take out: Fiat 500 - Lounge Hybrid and put that into an excel file.

I used:

```
async function getPageData(url, page) {
  await page.goto(url);

  const title = await page.$eval(
    "h1, id=carName",              
    (title) => title.textContent
  );
```

However, I keep getting error:

```
(node:6216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'h1[class=u-margin-bottom-none u-margin-bottom@tablet] .carName' is not a valid selector.
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:33
```

It has to do with     "h1, id=carName",  but I'm not sure how to write it in a way my scaper would recognize and take out Fiat 500 - Lounge Hybrid

Comment: `h1` does not have id `carName`, it has attribute `data-e2e-id`

Comment: As for the syntax error issue - you need to put quotes around the value in the attribute selector. `h1[class="u-margin-bottom-none u-margin-bottom@tablet"]`

Comment: @04FS This seems to be just generated selector

Comment: @Justinas are you saying puppeteer is generating selectors by itself, based on properties not even mentioned in the code? Well then it could at least do that _correctly_, haha.

Answer (score 1):

The h1 doesn't have an `id`, it's a data [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp). Instead you can do this:

```
async function getPageData(url, page) {
  await page.goto(url);

    const title = await page.$eval(
      'h1[data-e2e-id="carName"]',              
      (title) => title.textContent
    );
}
```

There are various ways to select an element, take a look here for a [quick reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Glad I could help!